# opendkim still not working - opendkim-genkey: openssl exited with status %d

Tags: linux, openssl

[opendkim not working - opendkim-genkey: openssl exited with status %d](https://superuser.com/questions/1470054/opendkim-not-working-opendkim-genkey-openssl-exited-with-status-d) offers no solutions.

The problem:

```
sudo opendkim-genkey -b 2048 -d example.com -D /etc/opendkim/keys/example.com -s mail -v
opendkim-genkey: generating private key
opendkim-genkey: openssl exited with status %d
```

If I run as root or use `sudo` I get the same error. No keys are generated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up purging openssl and reinstalling `sudo apt-get openssl`. I had to reinstall postfix and dovecot (and maybe will need to with others too) but in the end it seems to be working now.